# What happens to my thread when its RMI call is unresponsive?

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I have a question about calling a remote object from a thread: what happens to my thread when it is rendered unresponsive because it has blocked on a call to a server that appears to have gone into an infinite loop?

The current thread waits for a predetermined length of time for a channel's adviser (`ChannelAdviser`) thread which has been started earlier. I do this by retrieving the thread and calling the join operation with a time-out thus:

```
ChannelAdviser ca=receiver.getChannelAdviser();
if(ca==null){
    // Throw bespoke exception.
}

try{
    ca.join(receiver.getDrive().getCycleInterval());
}catch(InterruptedException ex){
    // Throw bespoke exception.
}

if(!ca.isAlive()){
    // All is good.
}else{
    /**
     *TODO Consider how one stops a channel adviser if the server
     * goes into an infinite loop while processing the message sent to it
     * by the given channel adviser. Does the adviser become a zombie
     * thread? Is this a potential memory leak as zombie threads
     * accumulate? How can the channel adviser be stopped so that should
     * the server be contacted again, and the same thing happens, there
     * is no risk of zombie channel advisers accumulating without limit?
     */
}
```

As the comment points out, I believe the current thread can recover from the fact that the server appears to have gone into an infinite loop. However, I am wondering what is going to happen to the channel's adviser thread. If the server keeps running forever, is this thread going to block forever?

If this is true, then it is obviously unacceptable. Is there any way to awaken the channel adviser from its potentially infinite slumber on the RMI client so that it can have a chance to terminate an hence release JVM resources?

Edit: The code that calls the remote object isn't disclosed here - just assume that the channel's adviser thread is responsible for making the call, and hence, if it is blocked, it will be blocked on this RMI call.

Thanks for your answers...

Owen.

PS Edit: I will accept this question is a duplicate if the suggested set of answers has provided a solution that allows me to set a time-out dynamically on my client and also allows me to create multiple time-outs depending upon which server is being called. The second answer: RMISocketFactory suggests that this can indeed be done. So, in advance of actually discovering that my assumption is true, I would suppose my question is duplicate.

Thanks again for your help (in advance of my impending discovery) EJP.

Comment: You can have each server provide its own RMIClientSocketFactory that sets a read timeout unique to that server,

Comment: Indeed, the time-out is agreed between the server and the client (actually the two devices act as servers and clients to each other), so at the moment, I'm assuming both devices can create and use these factory objects internally as they will both know the time-out values each other will use after they have gone through an initial "engagement" process. Each device may engage more than one other device at any point in time.